# How to create a graph in Mathematica with a specific style similar to the official documentation?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, drawing

(*Edited*) I am trying to create some 3D objects in Mathematica that have a similar style to the ones in the official documentation. For example: Below are some graphs on the "Physically Based Rendering" documentation.
[image]

I have tried using various functions in Mathematica, such as ParametricPlot3D, Graphics3D, and RegionPlot3D, but have not been able to achieve the desired style.
And I have also checked the source code in the offline documentation (see below), but there's only some minified code remaining making it hard to understand.

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[GridBox[{
    {
     Graphics3DBox[{{Text3DBox[
         FormBox[
          StyleBox["\<\"light\"\>", "Text",
           StripOnInput->False,
           FontSize->10], StandardForm], {1, -3, 3}, {1.5, -1.5}], Text3DBox[
         FormBox[
          StyleBox["\<\"view point\"\>", "Text",
           StripOnInput->False,
           FontSize->10], StandardForm], {0, -3.5, 1}, {-0.7, 3}], 
        {AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsoluteDashing[2.2], 
         Line3DBox[{{0, -3.5, 1}, {-0.7, -5., 1}}]}, Text3DBox[
         FormBox[
          StyleBox["\<\"object\"\>", "Text",
           StripOnInput->False,
           FontSize->10], StandardForm], {0, 0, 1}, {2, -3}]}, 
...
```

I have made some attempts to reproduce it like below, it seems making a 3D scene by code is a bit verbose and tedious IMHO. So I'm here to seeking a better way to accomplish it or if there is a framework/toolkit to help us to do it easier? btw, I'm really curious about how Mathematica team get this nice job done.

```
DynamicModule[{
  MakeHPlane, MakeVPlane, MakeVGrids,
  LightPos = {-1.0, 0, 4}, Object = Sphere[ {0.5, 0, 0.8}, 0.8], 
  ViewPos = {-3, 0, 1},
  FrontPlanePos = {-2, 0, 0},
  GetRay,
  ViewGrids,
  ViewRays,
  ViewGridsFilled,
  RaySphereIntersections,
  LengthenRay,
  PostProcRay,
  PostProcGrid
  },(*Right hand, Z up, CW?*)
 LengthenRay[a_, b_, t_] := 
  Module[{n = Normalize[b - a], l = Length[b - a]},
   {a, a + n l t}
   ];
 
 RaySphereIntersections[p1_, p2_, sphere_] := 
  RegionIntersection[sphere, Line[{p1, p2}]];
 MakeHPlane[origin_, extent_] :=
  (origin + # * extent) & /@ {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1,
      1, 0}};
 MakeVPlane[origin_, extent_] :=
  (origin + # * extent) & /@ {{0, -1, -1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 
     1}, {0, -1, 1}};
 MakeVGrids[c_, r_, plane_] := Module[{
    bounds ,
    range,
    part = {c, r},
    increment
    },
   bounds = List @@ BoundingRegion[plane];
   range = Abs /@ Subtract @@ bounds;
   increment = {range[[2]]/part[[1]], range[[3]]/part[[2]]};
   
   Table[
    MakeVPlane[{ bounds[[1]][[1]], i, j}, {0, increment[[1]]/2, 
      increment[[2]]/2}], {i, bounds[[1]][[2]], bounds[[2]][[2]], 
     increment[[1]]}, {j, bounds[[1]][[3]], bounds[[2]][[3]], 
     increment[[2]]}]
   ];
 ViewGrids = 
  MakeVGrids[8, 6, MakeVPlane[{-1.5, 0, 1.0},  {0, 1, 0.6}]] // 
   ArrayReshape[#, {Times @@ Dimensions[#]/12, 4, 3}] &;
 GetRay[p_] := 
  LengthenRay[ViewPos, Midpoint[List @@ BoundingRegion@p], 1.2];
 ViewRays = (p |-> Arrow[GetRay[p]]) /@ ViewGrids;
 PostProcRay[ray_] := Module[{p1, p2, intersection},
   {p1, p2} = (List @@ ray)[[1]];
   intersection = RaySphereIntersections[p1, p2, Object];
   
   If[RegionDimension@intersection >= 0, {GrayLevel[0], 
     Dashing[None], ray, Red, intersection}, {GrayLevel[0.7], 
     Dashing[0.01], ray}]
   ];
 (*performance ? *)
 PostProcGrid[grid_] := Module[{p1, p2, intersection},
   {p1, p2} = GetRay[grid];
   intersection = RaySphereIntersections[p1, p2, Object];
   If[RegionDimension@intersection >= 0, {Opacity[0.5], 
      Glow[RGBColor[0.97, 0.606, 0.081]], 
      FaceForm[GrayLevel[0]]}, {EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]], 
      FaceForm[None, None]}]~Join~{Polygon@grid}
   ];
 Graphics3D[{
   Text[Style["Light Source", "Text", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "SimSun", FontSize -> 12], LightPos + {-.3, 0, .5}],
   Text[Style["View Origin", "Text", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "SimSun", FontSize -> 12], 
    ViewPos + {-.3, 0, .5}],
   Object,
   Sphere[ViewPos, .1],
   Polygon[MakeHPlane[{0, 0, 0},  3]],(* ground plane*)
   {Glow[Orange], Sphere[LightPos, 0.05]},
   {Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[None], Opacity[.8], 
    Cone[{{-.5, 0.0, 3.2}, LightPos}, 1/3]},
   (*Polygon[MakeVPlane[{-1.5,0,1},  {0, 2, 1}]],*)
   PostProcGrid /@ ViewGrids,
   
   Arrowheads[Small],
   PostProcRay /@ ViewRays
   }, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", GrayLevel[0.3], LightPos}, {"Ambient", 
     GrayLevel[0.7]}}
  ]]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please limit the scope of the question and include Mathematica code (not an image) for a specific case that you have been experimenting with. Thanks.

Comment: The questioner's question I opine is quite reasonable. We were told where to find the image and the questioner was asking how the image was created. Going from the documentation image to Mathematicode is the question asked.

Comment: |-> should be \[Function] and your ArrayReshapes are malformed

Comment: I don't have access to that tutorial in local documentation.  Can the OP post the raw notebook graphics code if the question should be about minifying and guessing what originally produced it?

Comment: Hi @Adam the minified code can be found at @ IAmANaïf 's answer. And yes, I'm seeking for help to reproduce the result of the minified  code in the offline documentation.

Comment: Hi @Adam, could you please elaborate more about the usage of the `|->` and the `ArrayReshape` function? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly after reading the documentation.

Comment: @FreiZhang when I copy paste your code, |-> isn't valid syntax, \\[Function] should work (I didn't do the backslash correctly last time).  Also, your MakeVGrids function isn't working for me, which leads to problems evaluating some primitives.

Comment: @Adam maybe it's due to some compatibility issues, I'm using Mathematica 13. `|->` or `Function` will do the same work, And `ArrayReshape` is just for converting the nested list into a nx4x3 list.